# Are questions about production allowed

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask about the cost of buying a piece of music by a famous producer is that on topic?

Comment: I think that post covers this pretty thoroughly -- specific shopping advice / finding things is off-topic, but more general questions can be acceptable.